# Returning a Row from a Range

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm attempting to sort various chunks of text based upon category.  My program will convert certain GL accounts into another number; it will then sort those numbers in a group.  For example, A will have the items "'01,'06,10," B will have the items "02,20,50, 200."  There are gaps between the data, where the accounting software exports the total values.  the sort categories vary in length, which is why I need to use the find function; that, plus the total gaps.

I'm trying to return the row numbers from the grouped found items, then sort the data, throughout the financial statement, but the rows keep returning zero as a number.  When I try to use the string data type, they don't return anything.  I can confirm this through the message box i've temporarily included.  Naturally, the sort doesn't work because 0 doesn't exist on the the spreadsheet.

```
Public Count As Integer Public y As Integer Public StateGL As String
Public Lookupvalue As String Public Replacevalue As String Public c As
Range Public firstAddress As String

Sub SortData()
 
Dim rngfound As Range Dim Startrow As Integer Dim Endrow As Integer
 
For y = 2 To 100 Step 1
    Workbooks.Item("MonthlyReportCreator (version 2).xlsm").Worksheets.Item("lookuptable").Activate
    Lookupvalue = Cells(y, 1)
    Replacevalue = Cells(y, 3)
    StateGL = Cells(y, 2)
    If IsEmpty(Cells(y, 1)) = True Then   
        MsgBox ("finished sorting")
        Exit For
    End If

    Workbooks.Item("MonthlyReportCreator (version 2).xlsm").Worksheets.Item(1).Activate
    Set rngfound = Range("C1:C100").Find(What:=StateGL)
    If Not rngfound Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = rngfound.Address
        Startrow = rngfound.Row
        Do
            Set rngfound = Range("C1:C100").FindNext(After:=rngfound)
            Endrow = rngfound.Row
        Loop While rngfound.Address <> firstAddress
    Else
    End If  MsgBox (firstAddress.Row) 'Range(Cells(Startrow, 4), Cells(Endrow, 15)).Sort Key1:=Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo 
 
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `firstAddress.Row` can't work, because `firstAddress` is a String.  Try `Range(firstAddress).Row`

Comment: `Endrow  = Startrow + (Application.CountIf(Range("C1:C100"), StateGL) - 1)` assuming ColC is sorted.

Comment: FYI you can reference the workbook where your code is running using `ThisWorkbook` instead of (eg) `Workbooks.Item("MonthlyReportCreator (version 2).xlsm")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub SortData()
    Dim rngSort As Range, rngC As Range, Lookupvalue, StateGL, Replacevalue
    Dim wsLookup As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, m As Variant, numRows As Long, y As Long
    
    ' `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook where this code is running
    Set wsLookup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("lookuptable")
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set rngC = wsData.Range("C1:C" & wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row)
     
    For y = 2 To 100 'Step 1 is the default so typically not specified...
        
        Lookupvalue = wsLookup.Cells(y, 1).Value
        StateGL = wsLookup.Cells(y, 2).Value
        Replacevalue = wsLookup.Cells(y, 3).Value
        
        If Len(Lookupvalue) = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("finished sorting")
            Exit For
        End If
        
        m = Application.Match(StateGL, rngC, 0)          'find first
        If Not IsError(m) Then                           'found?
            numRows = Application.CountIf(rngC, StateGL) 'how many rows with this value?
            Set rngSort = rngC.Cells(m).Offset(0, 1).Resize(numRows, 12) 'D to O
            rngSort.Sort Key1:=rngSort.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo 'sort on D
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I upvoted, but unfortunately, the code doesn't seem to work.  I tried to see if something in my workbook is sorting, but it doesn't seem to be the case.  I really appreciate the help though.  The tricky part is that each sorting part fluxgates in size.  A lot of this coding thing seems to be trial and error.

Comment: Do you have a a shareable workbook?  Replace any sensitive data...

Comment: Sure, happy to upload a workbook, when I'm back in the office.  The information is merely a bunch of general ledger accounts for a government agency with dollar amounts, so nothing confidential, especially because people can request the information anyways.  In their infinite wisdom, the federal, and state governments each use their own chart of accounts, which is why I need to convert the exported data from my accounting software to another format.

Comment: if you prefer you can mail to me at  timjwilliams at gmail   Please first remove any "extra" VBA so I don't need to review it before allowing macros.